# How to make this effect?

Tags: dropdown, accordion, blogs, archive

Can anyone please help me in understanding how this blog archive works? I think it is using an accordion style. I'm trying to achieve the effect where the previous year below goes down when the top is opened. How to do this? I have absolute positioning in mine.

[image: picture of a blog archive list]

Comment: Can someone please help??? I been stuck with this forever.

Comment: Ok seems no one wants to help....jeeez.... I'm still stuck, and am totally clueless....